# How to use subscribe inside promise?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

My app checks if there are data in Ionic Storage and if there are none, it will load data from a JSON file to the Ionic Storage. This are my code:

quote.page.ts

```
quotes: Quote[] = [];
this.plt.ready().then(() => {
  this.storageService.loadQuotes().then(quotes => {
    this.quotes = quotes;
  });
});
```

storage.service.ts

```
quotes: Promise<Quote[]>;
data: any;

loadQuotes(): Promise<any> {
return this.storage.get(QUOTES_KEY).then((quotes: Quote[]) => {
  if (!quotes || quotes.length === 0) {
    this.http.get("../../assets/files/quotes.json").subscribe(result => {
      this.data = result["quotes"];
      this.quotes = result["quotes"];
      this.storage.set(QUOTES_KEY, this.data);
      return this.quotes;
    });
  }
});
}
```

My problem is, there are no data loaded in quotes in the quote.page.ts but data was loaded in the ionic storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return inside of subscribe, as the code will execute later. You can however wrap your subscribe inside of a promise and return that promise.

```
loadQuotes(): Promise<any> {
    return this.storage.get(QUOTES_KEY).then((quotes: Quote[]) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (!quotes || quotes.length === 0) {
                this.http.get("../../assets/files/quotes.json").subscribe(result => {
                    this.data = result["quotes"];
                    this.quotes = result["quotes"];
                    this.storage.set(QUOTES_KEY, this.data);
                    resolve(this.quotes);
                }, (error) => reject(error));
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not the right away to use subscribe inside a promise. You can change your function like below,

storage.service.ts

```
  async loadquotes(): Promise<any>{
   this.storage.get(QUOTES_KEY).then((quotes: Quote[]) => {
     if (!quotes || quotes.length === 0) {
        let response = await this.http.get("../../assets/files/quotes.json").toPromise();
        this.data = response ["quotes"];
        this.quotes = response ["quotes"];
        this.storage.set(QUOTES_KEY, this.data);
        return this.quotes;
    }
});
```

quote.page.ts

```
this.quotes = await this.storageService.loadQuotes();
```

This is the right way of using promise function. This will also do the same functionality you need. Please try out this and let me know if you find any other issues.